# Period Formula for Bifilar Pendulum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

I am a Grade 12 physics student working on an assignment that involves calculating how changing the suspension length of a bifilar pendulum affects the period of the pendulum.

My teacher told me to use the equation T=2π√(l/3g). I have to include the derivation of the equation and I am struggling to find resources outlining how this is done. If anyone can tell me how to derive the eqaution or direct me to a website that explains it, it would be really great :)